# Get data as JSON in controller

Tags: c#, json

I have this Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/Values",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Id: "1", Name: "Name1", Family: "Family1"
        }),
```

No I want to get `data` in controller so that I can save it to a text file with log4net. Currently I have written this code:

```
public void PostValues(Class1 cs)
    {
        var data = $"Id = {cs.Id}, Name = {cs.Name}, Family = {cs.Family}";
        Log.Debug($"POST Request, value = {data}");
    }
```

With model binding I can get data that is bound to class properties like above and then combine them like above. But I don't want to use this way because I have to go through all class properties. Is there any way to get data posted to controller as JSON? I'm sure that should be a way to get the following line in the controller:

```
Id: "1", Name: "Name1", Family: "Family1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a serializer to serialize the object to a string version. Here is how you will do it with [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
public void Post(Class1 value)
{
    var stringVersion = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    // use stringVersion  now.
}
```

Another option is to override `ToString()` in your class and use that as needed. You can include the relevant property values in the string returned by ToString()

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Family{ set; get; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return $"Id:{Id},Name:{Name}";
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call `ToString()` on your MyClass object.

```
public void Post(MyClass value)
{
    if(value!=null)
    {
       var stringVersion = value.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why to deserialize and then serialize a json. There must be a way to read the json as it is from the request. (t is possible with WCF, but I haven't used webapi)

Comment: @LB, `Request.InputStream` gives you raw data inside a controller. Outside it, you can get hold of raw data using `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`. But again, other than logging there may be additional processing on this data for which, accepting it as a model object would be the right way.

Comment: @JasonP, You don't need that attribute unless you are using web api.

Comment: @JasonP `[FromBody]` is not necessary for it to work. I just removed it from the answer.

Comment: @MatJ In web api it works as well. Why should I use it?

Comment: @JasonP, this is required when using simple parameter types(not a class) where it tries to bind from url. Classes except string are usually bound from body by default. In case of multiple parameters also, you can specify where to look for the data.(Web API)

Comment: @MatJ I know that it is required when using simple parameter types in WEB API and I also know how model binding works. But since I have used a class as parameter, the frombody seems not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JavaScriptSerializer`  to serialize class object into json object like this

```
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cs);
```